# What is the precedence of the `COLLATE` operator?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, collation

What is the precedence of the `COLLATE` operator? For example, in the following:

```
SELECT 'a' || 'B' COLLATE someting
```

I believe in this particular case it is interpreted as:

```
SELECT 'a' || ('B' COLLATE something)
```

But is there a listing of the exact rules on where the `COLLATE` keyword falls in? Is that section that says ["All other operators"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.0/operators.htm#:%7E:text=Operators%20have%20a%20precedence%20which,%22%20and%20%22%3E%3D%22.) ?

Comment: I think COLLATE is not considered an operator; it is a 'clause', and the whole section of 'COLLATE something' is called a `collation expression`. The collate expression applies to the operator (concatenate operator, in your case `||`), therefore it will apply to both arguments.  I don't understand why you would use a collate clause for concatenation, unless you use it in a comparison, sort or group, in your case.

Comment: @tinazmu The fact that `expr COLLATE collation` is called "collation expression" is just like `expr + expr` being called "additive expression". Or a more generic `expr operator expr` being called "binary expression". It's a common naming convention in programming language grammars.

Comment: On the other hand, it being named "the COLLATE clause" makes no sense to me. There are parts of the SELECT expression that are named clauses: "FROM clause", "WHERE clause", etc. But this COLLATE seems to have no resemblance to such clauses. I think it's merely a terminology mistake in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the [PostgreSQL documantation for operator precedence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) to be frustratingly lacking. While the [SQL syntax documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COLLATE-EXPRS) does state that:

> The COLLATE clause binds tighter than operators

**This is not correct.**

PostgreSQL documentation lists `.`, `::` and `[]` as operators in the operator-precedence table, and these bind tighter than `COLLATE`, as demonstrated by the following expressions not causing an error:

```sql
SELECT foo.bar COLLATE "POSIX" FROM foo;
SELECT 'Hello' :: VARCHAR COLLATE "POSIX";
SELECT t.arr[1] COLLATE "C" FROM (SELECT ARRAY['Hello'] AS arr) t;
```

At the same time the operators in the "any other operators" category bind looser than `COLLATE`. For example the `||` operator in question:

```sql
SELECT 2 || 'Hello' COLLATE "C"; -- works fine
SELECT 'Hello' || 2 COLLATE "C"; -- throws error
```

It also binds tighter than the `AT TIME ZONE` operator (another operator that's not listed in the operator precedence table). As demonstrated by the following code:

```sql
SELECT TIME '12:30' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' COLLATE "C"; -- works fine
SELECT TIME '12:30' COLLATE "C"; -- throws error
```

I have determined through experimentation that `AT TIME ZONE` binds tighter than unary `+`/`-` and looser than exponentiation (`^`).

The `COLLATE` operator also binds tighter than unary `+`/`-`:

```
-- throws error: collations are not supported by type double precision
SELECT +'2' COLLATE "C";
```

**I hereby present a revised PostgreSQL operator precedence table:**

- `.` (table/column name separator)
- `::` (type cast)
- `()` (**function call**)
- `[]` (array accessor)
- `+` `-` (unary plus, minus)
- **`COLLATE`**
- **`AT TIME ZONE` `AT LOCAL`**
- `^` (exponentiation)
- `*` `/` `%` (multiplication, division, modulo)
- `+` `-` (addition, subtraction)
- any other operator (e.g. `||`, `>>`, `|/`, `#`, `~`)
- **`ESCAPE`**
- `BETWEEN` `IN` `LIKE` `ILIKE` `SIMILAR`
- `<` `>` `=` `<=` `>=` `<>` `!=` (comparison)
- `IS` `ISNULL` `NOTNULL` `IS DISTINCT FROM`, etc.
- `NOT`
- `AND`
- `OR`
- **`INTERSECT`**
- **`UNION` `EXCEPT`**

Definitive source: [PostgreSQL source code](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/a6be0600ac3b71dda8277ab0fcbe59ee101ac1ce/src/backend/parser/gram.y#L812).

**Update:** The latest [development version of the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) now includes the `COLLATE` and `AT` operators.

Answer (score 2):

As so often, [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COLLATE-EXPRS) delivers:

> The `COLLATE` clause binds tighter than operators; parentheses can be used when necessary.

Comment: perfect, out of curiosity how did you search to find that? I often have trouble searching the postgres docs (or via a google search which is even harder).

Comment: I didn't search. I went to the PostgreSQL documentation, chapter 4 (SQL Syntax), there is chapter 4.2.10 (Collation Expressions).